# Why does my laptop require a hard boot every time it suspends?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, suspend, reboot, acpi

My laptop requires me to hard boot it everytime the screen suspends by pressing the power button for 40s.
It switches off and doesn't start again unless I spend 40s switching it on, it resets the time as well everytime, I don't know what to do as googling it resulted in no similar issues, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 dual booted with windows and this doesn't happen when I use windows on my laptop. I tried disabling fast boot on windows but that didn't work either.

Edit: Updates on System specs
My laptop is an Asus Vivobook 14 M413IA-EK581T with a ryzen 5 4500u processor. Ubuntu has been installed in dual boot configuration along with windows 10 for 3 months now and this problem has been there since then, I've tried uninstalling and installing again and that doesn't help. This problem didn't exist when I had dual booted Pop! OS and then fedora on my laptop previously.

Edit 2: This is what I mean by suspend, when automatic suspend is on my laptop switches off after stipulated time and then to switch it back on I have to press the power button for 40s. If I switch off that function then it drains my battery completely when I leave it on for extended periods of time but I don't have to press the power button for that long to switch it on [image: suspend]

Comment: I installed lightdm `sudo apt install lightdm` seems to of fixed it for me. (Intel Video)

Comment: Without knowing anything about your computer other than the fact that it's a notebook, it will be impossible to offer an answer. Could you [edit] your question to include the brand/model of your machine as well as some of the basic system specs? How long has Ubuntu been installed on the machine? Is it a single-boot or multi-boot system? With this information, it may be possible to begin narrowing the problem down ...

Comment: You need to disable Fast Startup in Windows (is this what you meant by Fast Boot? "Fast Boot" is a UEFI feature, not Windows). Also update UEFI before anything else.

Comment: @ChanganAuto If by disabling fast startup you mean what is described in [this](https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10#:~:text=Disabling%20Fast%20Startup&text=The%20Power%20Options%20window%20should,%22Turn%20on%20fast%20startup%22) tutorial then I have already done it.

Comment: @EODCraftStaff that didn't fix the issue for me but it did change the login page to something more beautiful so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why? Because, unfortunately, power management on laptops by Linux is not always working well. This is because Linux is an open source operating system created by volunteers all over the world, whereas hardware is produced by manufacturers that not always disclose how their hardware works.

Sleep state (suspend to RAM) works well in general. Hibernation (suspend to disk) does not work well in many cases, to the extend that it is not enabled by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: From what I've read about and tried I don't think my laptop suspends either suspend to RAM or suspend to disk, it only seems to support suspend to idle and I don't really know the difference between any of them.

Comment: You referred to "suspend" in your question, so that is why I refer to these two ways of suspending. Just locking the screen is not "suspend" and should usually not be a problem. Of course, we can not guess what you mean under "suspend", so it is likely necessary to edit your question and provide more detail, so one can infer what "suspend" means to you.

Comment: I referred to suspend because from my understanding suspending the system is what is causing the problem.